# When is the 'require' necessary when using a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I noticed for some gems you must include it in the file where you want to use it like this `require 'a_gem'`, but this is not always the case.

I am going to compose a gem by myself. What should I do if I do not want to add the `require 'my_gem'` to the .rb file when using it?

Comment: What do you mean? You should always require a gem in order to use it. But you can require a gem in one file and use it in another one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, an application that is using a gem needs to require the gem:

```
require "my_awesome_gem"
MyAwesomeGem.do_something_great
```

However, if an application is using [bundler](http://bundler.io), which defines the application's gem in a file called "Gemfile":

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'my_awesome_gem'
```

then the application may invoke bundler in a way that automatically requires all of the gems specified in the Gemfile:

```
require "bundler"
Bundler.require
MyAwesomeGem.do_something_great
```

Rails projects use `Bundler.require`, so a Rails application will not need to explicitly require a gem in order to use it: Just add the gem to the Gemfile and go.

For more about `Bundler.require`, see the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/gemfile.5.html)

For more about how Rails uses Bundler, see [How Does Rails Handle Gems?](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-does-rails-handle-gems/) by Justin Weiss.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. If you want to write a Gem and use it, it needs to be required somewhere.

This "somewhere" could be explicit in one of your scripts, it could be written in a [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) or it could be required by another script/gem that is required by your script.

If you write a gem, Ruby will not include it automatically in all your scripts.

Finally, if you publish it, should every single Ruby script on earth magically require it and execute your code?

I suppose that the project you have seen which didn't use `require 'a_gem'` was using a Gemfile.